# computer architecture cache pollution

Tags: caching, memory, memory-management, operating-system, cpu-architecture

I read from the Wikipedia is that cache pollution occurs when we access some data once and after that we do not use that data and since precious cache space occupied by such data. Some useful data is evicted in replacement.

is my understanding correct or am I missing something? Can I get more information on cache pollution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most cache memories use the *last recently used* replacement algorithm, i.e. they replace data in the cache that were not used longest. So if you fill the whole cache memory with new data, the data loaded earliest will be replaced, even if they will be used again, and the data loaded later not.
It therefore makes sense to keep the functionality of a cache memory in mind, if data intensive algorithms are developed.
I don't know which Wikipedia article you have read, but [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_pollution) is a good example.